# Creating a .NET Service Layer that Serves up JSON: WCF or MVC Content as JSON?

Tags: .net, wcf, azure

Hello and thanks for looking!

## Background

I am designing a greenfield application using .NET4 w/C# that will be packaged for/by Azure and run in the cloud.

One of the main functions of this application will be to listen for requests coming out of other cross-domain apps throughout the Internet, authenticate the request (method for doing that has not yet been determined), and then respond with data in the form of a JSON object.

This application will serve up data on a subscription/API basis and I will have no control or advanced knowledge of where future requests will originate.

In the past, I have created a MVC3 project in my solution as a "service" layer which simply listened on certain URLs (e.g. "mydomain.com/json") for data requests from the *same* domain.  In response to the request, I would grab some data from SQL (entities actually), serialize it into JSON and then return it as `return Content(foo,application/json)` via the action result.  This has worked GREAT.

The JSON will likely *always* be requested via ajax running on a client machine, so I am not that worried about threads being blocked on the server.

Please note, I know very little about WCF service projects and very little about Azure.

## Question

Although I am very happy with the way my MVC JSON service pattern works in other applications, are there any major reasons I should NOT do this?  Major reasons I *should* be using WCF instead?

I am tempted to subscribe to the "if it aint broke don't fix it" philosophy, but I know that is not best practice.

I look forward to reviewing the advice of the brilliant minds on Stack Overflow regarding this matter!

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no arguments against using MVC methods, I am going to stick with them.  I have found .NET MVC3 to be extremely flexible as a service brokerage layer, especially when using [JsonFx](http://jsonfx.net/) as a JSON serializer allowing for low-cost data transport between tiers.